# Why does Collections.sort in reverse order resulted in incomplete sort?

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

I have a list of files that I am trying to sort in the order of the most recent modified date to the least recent. The date is stored as a long value (milli seconds since the epoch) and I used Collections.sort to sort the files. I want the files to go from most recent to least recent (top to bottom), so I did R2-R1 instead of R1-R2 in the Comparator. The code I used is shown below:

```
            Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<RecordingFile>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(RecordingFile R1, RecordingFile R2) {
                int x = (int) (R2.getLastModfied()-R1.getLastModfied());
                return Integer.compare(x, 0);
            }
        });
```

This code resulted in something like so:

```
14-04-2022
10-04-2022
06-04-2022
05-04-2022
20-03-2022
...
18-04-2022
18-04-2022
17-04-2022
```

The list is somehow ordered correctly but incorrectly at the same time. The files are ordered in parts instead of fully. I tried shuffling the list before ordering and it resulted in a different order but still the same behaviour (ordered but in parts). To solve this, I did R1-R2 in the comparator and then reverse the sorted list. This resulted in a fully ordered list that takes into account all items in the list.

I was wondering if anyone knows why this happened?

Comment: Could it be that the operation overflows because you cast the result to an int? Anyways, I would do this with the declarative `Comparator.comparing(RecordingFile::getLastModfied).reversed()` instead of implementing the comparator manually.

Comment: Aside from main question, why not simply use more readable `return Long.compare(R2.getLastModfied(), R1.getLastModfied());` instead? BTW if `getLastModfied` is returns `long` then subtraction will also result in `long` which takes 64 bits. By casting it to `int` which is 32 bit type you are taking last 32 bits from long and if those bits will start with which 1 it will represent negative value even if original `long` was positive.

Comment: If the difference between the two days is more than (2^32)-1 milliseconds, then your cast will overflow. That is 49.71 days.

Comment: @marstran is correct. From March 20 to April 18 are 29 days or 2 505 600 000 milliseconds (depending on time of day, summer time and such). Converted to an `int` this becomes -1 789 367 296.

Comment: Yes, I agree overflow is the cause of the problem. Thank you all for identifying it. I've tried both solutions and they both work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in the comments, try using `Comparator.comparing(RecordingFile::getLastModfied).reversed()` instead of doing it manually.

If you decide to still do it manually, check the `lastModfied` type because if it's a `long` then you shouldn't be returning the final result of the comparison as `int`

Comment: final result of the compare method will always be `int`

Comment: Still better: `Comparator.comparingLong(RecordingFile::getLastModfied)` and so on. When using the `comparing` method, you are doing needless boxing and unboxing.